# Gene transfer between Gram positive and Gram negative bacteria?

Tags: genetics, bacteriology

How does transfer of genetic material occur between Gram positive and Gram negative bacteria?

Comment: By horizontal gene transfer.. but would you add more details to your question ? then the answers can be specific.

Comment: Do you want the exact mechanism ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this two links:

- [Exchange of genetic information](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/48203/bacteria/272363/Exchange-of-genetic-information)
  and
- [Gene transfer between distantly related bacteria](http://web.mit.edu/kdrinkwa/Public/tklab/for-mfpapers/Mazodier91.pdf)

Especially the second should answer a lot of questions.